# Subchunk2ID in the header of the wav file on the iPhone

Tags: audio, core-audio, wav

Hello wonderful people of the audio computing world!

Allright, so I've managed to successfully parse the header of a wav file and spit out the samples into an array. This I did on my Mac using code found at the [bottom of this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10442711).

Now I've integrated the C code onto my iPhone device, but it EXITS FAILURE when it hits this piece of code:

```
/* Subchunk2ID */
fread(buf, 1, 4, stdin);
buf[4] = '\0';
if (strcmp((char*)buf, "data")) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

The file is in wav format recorded using the SpeakHere example project. I just changed the format from the original .caf to a .wav.

Is there something particular about how core-audio creates a wav file that would make it different to parse from a regular wav file?

How could I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically- why are you parsing the file manually vs. letting Core Audio to do it for you?

Comment: @sbooth, I'm trying to stick all the samples of a wav file into an array. Any suggestion on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AudioFile to do this, assuming you don't need to convert the file's data to a different format.  Your code will flow like this:

```
AudioFileOpenURL()
AudioFileReadPackets()
AudioFileClose()
```